# How to detect a subclass of a generic abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.type

I want to create a class hierarchy based on a generic abstract class. I need to be able to recognize my subclasses in a codebase. I tried to use `Type.IsSubclassOf`, but it did not work as expected.

```
namespace TestIsSubclassOf
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var testClass = typeof(TestClass);
            var isSubclass = testClass.IsSubclassOf(typeof(TestBaseClass<>)); // expected - true, actual - false
        }
    }

    public abstract class TestBaseClass<T>
    {
    }

    public class TestClass : TestBaseClass<int>
    {
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to recognize `TestBaseClass` subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if your `testClass` is a subclass of `TestBaseClass<int>` instead of `TestBaseClass<>` since you could inherit from a different generic 'version' of this class.

So using the following code `isSubclass` returns `true`:

```cs
var testClass = typeof(TestClass);
var isSubclass = testClass.IsSubclassOf(typeof(TestBaseClass<int>));
```

---

If it is the case that you want to check if the class inherits `TestBaseClass` regardless of the used generic type you can try the following:

```
var testClass = typeof(TestClass);
if (testClass.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
    testClass.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(TestBaseClass<>))
{
    //testClass inherits from TestBaseClass<>
}
```

Comment: And how is this generic? I think the point is the OP doesn't know the underlying type (`int`).

Comment: @JuanR added solution for that case as well.